# Adding an array element to an array in PHP

Tags: php

Just confused on appending an array to another array. My Intention is to supply the search parameter to the $arg array.

```
$args = array(

                     'posts_per_page' => -1,
                     'post_type'    => 'product',
                     'meta_key'     => $orderby,
                     'orderby'  => $num_orderby,
                     'order'        => $order);
```

I want to add an another element `'s'           =>  $search_str
to $arg array.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial sentence asks about appending an array to another array, but then you ask about appending values to an array, so let's learn both!

To append to an array, this is most easily done with :

```
$args[] = 'New Value';
```

This simply appends directly to the array and is the same as the below array_push method.

The [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) method.

> `array_push()` treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed
>   variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the
>   number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as: `$array[] = $var;`

**Push to array `array_push()`:**

```
array_push($args, "value");
```

In case you were wondering about merging some arrays, keep reading.

You can merge arrays by using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

**To merge arrays:**

```
array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

This appends `$array2` to `$array1`

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
$args['s'] = $search_str;
```

So this will get append to the existing array